# What extra security features does windows 8 offer over windows 7?

Tags: security, windows-8

What improvements/additions to security have been made to Windows 8 as compared to Windows 7?

Comment: You are taking the Win8Challenge way too seriously. Even asking a question for which you know the answer too :)

Comment: There are far to many to list.  One major feature that only exists with IE10 and Windows 8 ( currently ) is the ability to block a known verified malicous file.

Comment: @GaneshR.: I didn't at first, but saw that some people had done. A bit discouraged by this question's -2 score, but I'd hoped I was asking useful questions.

Comment: @GaneshR. - Thus the reason this question should be voted down.  This information is already out there, there likely is even already an answer to a different question, that could be applied to this question.

Comment: @GaneshR.: There's nothing wrong with self-answering, in fact, it's encouraged.

Comment: The information being on the internet isn't a reason to close surely, that's not the impression I get from reading the various SE blogs. If there's a duplicate then obviously that's fine. :)

Comment: Also, I thought this might be a question many users of not-windows (in particular) might be asking.

Comment: @GaneshR. Asking questions you know the answer to is encouraged a SE sites.

Answer (score 2):

Based on information from these articles there have been many improvements:
http://www.askvg.com/windows-8-comes-with-security-improvements-to-protect-you-from-malware/
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/security/what-windows-8-has-done-to-improve-security/8269
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/protecting-you-from-malware)

Microsoft use better practices when developing code:

> Microsoft uses the Security Development Lifecycle (SDL) to build Windows with the best security design, development and testing practices available.

MS have worked to reduce the likelihood of attacks.

> Windows 8 includes mitigation enhancements that further reduce the likelihood of common attacks.

Windows defender is improved.

> Windows 8 will also provide you protection with a significantly improved version of Windows Defender. The improvements to Windows Defender will help protect you from all types of malware, including viruses, worms, bots and rootkits by using the complete set of malware signatures from the Microsoft Malware Protection Center

Protections are in place to stop malware that effects parts of the boot process (called SecureBoot).

> When you use a PC that supports UEFI-based Secure Boot, Windows secured boot will help ensure that all firmware and firmware updates are secure, and that the entire Windows boot path up to the antimalware driver has not been tampered with.

SmartScreen has been improved.

> Windows 8 will help protect you with reputation-based technologies when launching applications as well as browsing with Internet Explorer.

---

Summary:

> In conclusion, we’ve taken a very broad approach to improving the level of protection you’ll get from malware in Windows 8, including the use of SDL processes to be secure by design, the implementation and upgrading of mitigations to help protect you against exploits used by malware, improvements to Windows Defender to provide you with real-time protection against all categories of malware, and the use of URL and application reputation to help protect you against social engineering attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Well first off, there is UEFI to protect the pre-OS environment.

> UEFI (Unified Extensible Firmware Interface) is managed through the UEFI forum, a collection of chipset, hardware, system, firmware, and operating system vendors. The forum maintains specifications, test tools, and reference implementations that are used across many UEFI PCs.

[image]

You can read [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/protecting-you-from-malware) on how security has been improved since Windows XP. Smart Screen is now enabled for apps too.

A major improvement is the fact that Flash is now managed by Windows Update, flash is buggy and with it under Windows Update, it's a little more safe.

It should also be noted that a new version of Windows Defender is included and it includes the features of Microsoft Security Essentials(it's awesome).

Comment: Only the version of Flash built into IE10 is handled by `Windows Update` if you use a browser that does not have built in support, then you would have to install Flash by itself for that browser, just like always.

Comment: Only Firefox and Opera get excluded. Something is better than nothing